# How to ignore a single character in RegEx

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

How can I ignore a single-quote from getting through to this?

```
function FixNameForLink($str){
    // Swap out Non "Letters" with a -
    $text = preg_replace('/[^\\pL\d]+/u', '-', $str); 
    // Trim out extra -'s
    $text = trim($text, '-');
    // Convert letters that we have left to the closest ASCII representation
    $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
    // Make text lowercase
    $text = strtolower($text);
    // Strip out anything we haven't been able to convert
    $text = preg_replace('/[^-_\w]+/', '', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

I'm given a name `Steven's Barbecue`, and I want to convert it to a proper link, like `steven-s-barbecue`, but somehow I need to be able to convert the ' into another character like `_`

For clarification (to avoid confusion...), the link needs to be `steven_s-barbecue`

Comment: why not just use urlencode() ??

Comment: because I don't need +'s or %20's in the url for things like spaces... I need -.

Comment: So `\\pL` contains the apostrophe?

Comment: its a link,urlencode() will work, what other problem do yo think your solving

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Your code produces "steven-s-barbecue" for input "Steven's Barbecue"... which is perfectly valid. If you want to replace quote with an underscore, use a str_replace() before you start.

Comment: why is the sky blue? why is the grass green?   Can we start being a bit more constructive here, and address the question at hand?  I didn't ask `How do I urlencode a name`, I asked a specific question for a specific problem... my reasons for doing it this way are my own, and should be accepted as that.

Comment: @phil-lavin tried that, but I assume the regex in the function is taking the underscore as an invalid character

Comment: Is _ valid for anything other than a replacement for a quote?

Comment: no.  That's it's only purpose

Comment: Ok, I see. One sec...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution would be to permit the use of the quote character in your initial replacements and then replace it with an _ at the end. Example below:

```
<?php
function FixNameForLink($str){
    // Swap out Non "Letters" with a -
    $text = preg_replace('/[^\pL\d\']+/u', '-', $str);
    // Trim out extra -'s
    $text = trim($text, '-');
    // Convert letters that we have left to the closest ASCII representation
    $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
    // Make text lowercase
    $text = strtolower($text);
    // ' has been valid until now... swap it for an _
    $text = str_replace('\'', '_', $text);
    // Strip out anything we haven't been able to convert
    $text = preg_replace('/[^-_\w]+/', '', $text);
    return $text;
}

var_dump(FixNameForLink("Steven's Barbecue")); // steven_s-barbecue
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think my confusion was because I assumed `$text = preg_replace('/[^\\pL\d\']+/u', '-', $str);` was stripping everything out first.

Comment: the [^XXXX] group means match anything except these characters and the + means one or more. So it's saying replace everything but 'letter characters' (\pL), digits (\d) and single quotes (\'). The \\ before the p is actually redundant and could be shortened to \p. I've edited the above to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Run a `str_replace`?

```
$text = str_replace("'", '_', $str);
$text = preg_replace('/[^_\\pL\d]+/u', '-', $text);
```

You could also run a `urlencode()` after all of your functions to the final product just to be on the safe side since you're trying to use dashes instead of `%20` for spaces